# Will F# be supported in the Windows Developer Program for IoT

Tags: f#, windowsondevices

I am an F# programmer and would like to use F# on the Galielo board which is part of Micorosoft's Windows Developer Program for IoT. Is it supported?

REF: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/dn786369

Answer (score 3):

Not initially, at least.  See the FAQs [here](http://ms-iot.github.io/content/WelcomeAndFAQ.htm):

> Q: Will you support C#/WinRT/.NET/Node/JS… ?
>
> A: For this first preview
>   release, we’re focusing on C++ and Arduino compatibility. In future
>   iterations, our intent is to support the Universal App model announced
>   at Build.